# Multiplying vectors of uneven length and summing the result

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum

How can I for every element of a vector calculate several elements from another vector?

For example, `x=[1,2]` and `y=[1,2,3,4]` then I need to multiply and sum each element of `x` with all elements of `y`, like so;

```
x = [1,2]
y = [1,2,3,4]
z = [x1*y,x2*y] = [x1*y1+x1*y2+x1*y3+x1*y4,x2*y1+x2*y2+x2*y3+x2*y4]
```

The vectors can have unlimited elements.

Comment: [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) can help you here, try `z = sum(y'*x,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = randi(10,3,1);
y = randi(10,4,1);

tmp = bsxfun(@times,x.',y); % Pre-R2016b
% tmp = x.'*y; % Post R2016b method
out = sum(tmp(:));
```

One can use either `bsxfun` or implicit expansion to create a matrix of `numel(x) * numel(y)` size and then sum over the flattened array to get to a final result.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply `x` with sum of `y`

```
result = x * sum(y)
```